# "$count{$current}" how this code will be interpreted in php?

Tags: php

I just saw a piece of php code. I couldn't find an explanation how the interpretor will evaluate this statement `$newstring .= "$count{$current}";`.

```
$string = "111221";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {

$current = $string[$i];
$count = 1;

while(isset($string[$i + $count]) && ($string[$i + $count] == $current)) $count++;
$newstring .= "$count{$current}";

$i += $count-1;
}

print $newstring;
```

Anybody please explain this line `"$count{$current}"`. I imagine the doubles quotes is for typecasting to string. But, `$count` and `$current` should be numbers. Then what will be the meaning of the curly braces?

Comment: It's to distinguish as a variable and ensure that its treated as such when there may be potential ambiguity

Comment: See the "Complex (curly) syntax" section of the [PHP Docs on strings](https://secure.php.net/language.types.string)

Comment: Gotcha. Write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {.
Thanks Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newstring .= "$count{$current}";
```

is the same for

```
$newstring .= $count . $current;
```

Comment: they are equivalent:
echo $a;
echo "$a";
echo "{$a}";

Comment: Thanks Maksim. I tested. It gives the same output.